# Optimization involving the length of $x$ as the perimeter of two geometric objects

Tags: calculus, optimization

I am having problems understanding how to solve the following optimization problem:

*A piece of wire 12 m long is cut into two pieces, the length of the first piece being x m. The first piece is bent into a circle, and the other is bent into a rectangle with length twice the width. Give an expression for the total area A enclosed in the two shapes in terms of x.*

In my attempt to solve this was my order of operation:

**1. Set up the equation**

*Perimeter of the circle*
$2{\pi}r =x$

*Solving for r*
$r= \frac{x}{2{\pi}}$

*Perimeter of the rectangle*

*Solving for w*
$w = {\frac{12-x}{6}}$

**2. Apply both the width and radius to the respective formula's for obtaining the area. Therefore reaching the conclusion**

$$A(x) = {\pi}\left(\frac{x}{2{\pi}}\right)^2 + 2\left({\frac{12-x}{6}}\right)^2$$

Please reject or confirm this answer for me, 
Thank you for your help,
Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is correct. You left out a few minor steps, which makes it slightly harder to follow. With more steps it would be:

$$l=2w=2\left({\frac{12-x}{6}}\right)$$
$$\begin{align}
A(x) &= A_{circle}(x)+A_{rectangle}(x) \\
 &= \pi r^2+lw \\
 &= {\pi}\left(\frac{x}{2{\pi}}\right)^2 + 2\left({\frac{12-x}{6}}\right)\left({\frac{12-x}{6}}\right) \\
 &= {\pi}\left(\frac{x}{2{\pi}}\right)^2 + 2\left({\frac{12-x}{6}}\right)^2
\end{align}$$